# How to get checkbox values in django application

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, python-3.x, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use a check box control in a simple `django` application. Code Logic seems to be fine, But I am getting an empty `fruit` list (`[None, None]`). I don't know why it's not working, Can anybody point out the mistake. Thanks in advance

**index.html**

```
<div class="form-check">
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Apple" id="apple">
<label class="form-check-label" for="apple">Apple</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Mango" id="mango">
<label class="form-check-label" for="mango">Mango</label>
</div>
```

**view.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    fruit = []
    fruit.append(request.POST.get('apple'))
    fruit.append(request.POST.get('mango'))
```

Comment: I dont think you need to use a POST request as this normally requires a CSRF token.. use GET instead unless it is sensitive data

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Daniel mentioned, you have to add a `name` attribute to form elements, so they are submitted to the server.

**index.html**

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Apple" id="apple" name="fruits">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="apple">Apple</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Mango" id="mango" name="fruits">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="mango">Mango</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

That way, you can get a list of fruits in your view:

**views.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    fruits = request.POST.getlist('fruits')
```

The `fruits` variable would be a list of check inputs. E.g.:

```
['Apple', 'Mango']
```

Comment: How to handle when the checkbox has also the `checked` attribute set? It seems in that case the value of `fruits` will be: `['on', 'on']` and there is no indication which fruits were selected.

Comment: @caram did you find solution?

Answer (score 1):

`input` elements need a `name` attribute, otherwise the browser does not send any data.

Comment: But bootstrap controls have `id` tag instead of `name`

Comment: @OliviaBrown You can add the name attribute, no problem. The `id`s are primarily for the labels.